# Access private static class property from Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, singleton

I have a class similar to this:

```
class My_Class {
    private static $array = null;
    private static $another_array = null;

    private function __construct() {
        self:$another_array = array( 'data' );
    }

    // This gets executed from jQuery Ajax when user clicks a button
    public static function process_ajax() {
        self::generate_html();
    }

    private static function generate_html() {
        if ( ! self::$array ) {
            self::$array = array( 'some data' );
        }
    }

    // This gets executed when user is trying to save Ajax generated form
    public static function save_ajax_form() {
        print_r( self::$another_array ); // prints [0] => 'data'
        self::validate_data();
    }

    private static function validate_data() {
        // WHY DOES THIS EVALUATE TRUE? 
        if ( ! is_array( self::$array ) ) {

        }

    }
}
```

How can I access `My_Class::$array` property from an Ajax call?

Comment: Are you sure the issue is with accessing the private property and not the private methods?

Comment: @doublesharp well, the code gets executed all the way to the if statement where i'm checking if it's an array

Comment: would have to see the whole code to see why it behaves that way, but generally speaking private methods should only be accessible when called within the class. Since PHP is PHP you can actually access a private method from any instance of that class, in languages like Java it would be the specific instance of that object.

Comment: @doublesharp edited my question with more code

Comment: You aren't calling `generate_html()` so the `$array` is null, and not an array.

Comment: @doublesharp I'm calling `generate_html()` on my first ajax call

Comment: Alas, PHP is not like other languages and `static` doesn't mean what you think it does... it is going to reinitialize the variable on every request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though you are declaring the variable `static` it is going to be initialized to `null` on every request - PHP is "stateless" in this way, static variables will not persist accross requests. Since you do want to persist the value you will need to use something like `$_SESSION`, `APC` or `memcached` to hold the value of `$array`.

When your ajax calls `save_ajax_form()` it immediately then calls `validate_data()`. The `$array` variable is still initialized to null since the call to `generate_html()` happened in a different request, so the check to see if it is not an array will return true.

See: [Does static variables in php persist across the requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520132/does-static-variables-in-php-persist-across-the-requests)

Comment: but i'm not doing a page refresh… and how can i call another `private static array` in that same `save_ajax_form()` method that gets populated in my class constructor then? But not the array in question

Comment: Every AJAX request is, well, a request, the same as if you had refreshed the page from the server's perspective.

Comment: hmm… ok… but i'm confused… So the state of `$another_array` stays the same because in my ajax call to the `save_ajax_form` makes the `__construct` get executed also, and thus, re-populated?

Comment: Exactly, the object constructor will be called on every request and set it to the value you have there. If tried to change it to something else, it would go back to the value in the constructor on the second request.

Comment: Ok, so I'll have to rethink my logic again. All I tried to achieve with populating that $array in my first ajax call was to avoid another database query. Thanks for the lesson. :)

Comment: That's where using `$_SESSION` or a caching plugin like `APC` or `memcached` could come in handy instead of a static property. Check out the link in my answer, it has some example code.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you could either change the scope declaration from `private` to `public`, or if you want to keep private, add a public accessor:

```
public function getArray()
{
    self::process_ajax();

    return self::$array;
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry but that didn't help, still getting the `$array === null`. Both setter and getter didn't help either

Comment: Are you certain that the array is populated?

Comment: yes i am… in `generate_html` i'm printing the array `self::$array` and it's all there

Comment: @MikePurcell the problem is that `$array` is set in the first request but then reinitialized to null on the second request.

Comment: @doublesharp: Didn't see the code, nor mention about a 2nd request. I updated the code, where it will initialize the array regardless of first or 19th request.

Comment: @MikePurcell No worries, that info wasn't there a few minutes ago :)

Comment: @doublesharp: Got it. Thx for clarifying, as I get older my eyesight comes into question.